# Triple integral, finding the volume between two planes and a surface in 3D

Tags: calculus, integration, 3d, volume

[image]

So I have tried to solve this problem, but I'm running into a problem, because the top circle (intersection of the function with z=1) when you project it onto the xy plane is smaller than the circle that it creates with the plane z=0.  so when you try to compute the integral you only get the cylinder part :/ can someone please help me with this I've been stuck on this question for over a day now....
Here is my attempt :
[image: My attempt and what the graph looks like]

Maybe I have to change the integrations, like change it from dzdydx to dydxdz or dxdydz etc..  But I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: When $r\in[0,0.5]$ your solid is bounded above by $z=1$ but when $r\in(0.5,1]$ your solid is bounded above by $z=\frac{1}{r}-1$. If you want to use the order $dzdrd\theta$ you'll have to use two separate triple integrals.

Answer (score 0):

In cylinder coordinates with $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and Jacobian $r$:
$$
V=\int_0^1 dz \int_{x^2+y^2\le 1/(z+1)^2} dx dy
=
\int_0^1 dz \int_{r=0}^{1/(z+1)} r dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi
$$
$$
=
2\pi \int_0^1 dz \int_{r=0}^{1/(z+1)} r dr
=
\pi \int_0^1 dz r^2\mid _{0}^{1/(z+1)}
$$
$$
=
\pi \int_0^1 dz \frac{1}{(z+1)^2}
=
\pi \int_1^2 dz \frac{1}{z^2}
=
\pi  [-\frac{1}{z}]\mid_1^2=\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$